# Processing material on images to a separate graph in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm processing a file of images that are in encoded in RGB and contain material. The material is any non-background pixel with the background being purple or RGB(37, 150, 190)

At the moment I have 2 graphs, the graph on the right displays the images in the file one by one and the graph on the left is the mask of it I'm trying to create.

What I'm trying to implement is functionality where if there is material present on the image graph, then using the gridlines, any boxes occupied by that material will be filled in with white on the left graph(*"img" graph*)

**Example Images**
[image: Example]
[image: Example]

**Expected Solution**

Using the above image an an example this is what I'm trying to get it to look like in a sense, the boxes with the marked circles are the boxes I would want to be filled in completely white as the material from the image is within the bounds of each of these boxes

[image: Example Solution]

The approach I was using so far was copying over the image to the left graph and then have a moving slide that moves from box to box to check if there are pixels in there that are not black(background), and if so then to fill in that entire box white before moving onto to the box but I'm not sure on how to exactly implement that after copying the image over.

This is the segment of my code I modified to begin doing this:

```
for i in range(len(tiles)):
    tile_data = tiles[i][0].data
    bg_color = np.array([37, 150, 190])
    tissue_mask = (tile_data != bg_color)
    img[tissue_mask] = tile_data[tissue_mask]
    axs[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    axs[1].imshow(tiles[i][0].data)
    plt.pause(1)
```

**FULL CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wsi_utils.wsi import WSI, Slide, Path

plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 0.1

# Import class
wsi = WSI()

# Mask file
mask_file = Slide(wsi, Path("60d21e3e6ddf4448d476c7d0.msk"))
tiles = mask_file.read_tiles(10, [-1])

# Define image size
img_size = (512, 512)

# Create a black image
img = np.zeros(img_size, dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw vertical lines
x_coords = [64, 192, 320, 448]
y_coords = [64, 192, 320, 448]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))

# Draw gridlines on the image
for x in x_coords:
    for y in y_coords:
        axs[0].axvline(x=x, color='white')
        axs[0].axhline(y=y, color='white')
        axs[1].axvline(x=x, color='white')
        axs[1].axhline(y=y, color='white')

for i in range(len(tiles)):
    axs[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    axs[1].imshow(tiles[i][0].data)
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You just need a list that, for each box in the grid, stores its top-left and bottom-right corner and the centre point where its white circle needs to be drawn. Then just iterate through the list, masking the right-side image with the grid. Count the number of pixels not matching the background colour, and draw white circle at centre if non zero.

Comment: please clarify the entire question. [ask]

Comment: @MarkSetchell Apologies Mark, I don't think I made it properly clear what I was asking. What I'm trying to get is the entire box filled in white, not just a white circle in the middle. Would the approach you suggested still work for this instead?

Comment: That's even easier. You only need one pair of coordinates for each grid square. Mask or crop the right image to the coordinates. Count the number of masked pixels not matching the background, and if non-zero, fill left grid square with white.